# How to calculate the new coefficients of a Conic section that has been rotated, based on the previously known coefficient values?

Tags: analytic-geometry, conic-sections

Suppose I have an equation for a conic section, with the usual meaning:
$$Ax^{2} + Bxy + Cy^{2} + Dx + Ey + F = 0$$

I know the current values of the conic $A,B,C, D, E, F$ and the angle of rotation $\Theta$. I'd like to now rotate the conic by some amount $\phi$, the new rotation angle therefore being (${\Theta} + {\phi}$).

I know that the values of the [coefficients can be calculated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse#General_ellipse) as follows (with the usual meaning of $a,b$ and $(x0,y0)$, all of which are known):

\begin{aligned}A&=a^{2}(\sin \Theta )^{2}+b^{2}(\cos \Theta )^{2}\\B&=2\left(b^{2}-a^{2}\right)\sin \Theta \cos \Theta \\C&=a^{2}(\cos \Theta )^{2}+b^{2}(\sin \Theta )^{2}\\D&=-2Ax_{\circ }-By_{\circ }\\E&=-Bx_{\circ }-2Cy_{\circ }\\F&=Ax_{\circ }^{2}+Bx_{\circ }y_{\circ }+Cy_{\circ }^{2}-a^{2}b^{2}.\end{aligned}

Now, I could simply plug my new value of ($\Theta + \phi$) in the above equations to obtain my new Conic coefficients. However, I am trying to find out if I can use the *already known values of the coefficients at angle ($\Theta$)* and simply add/multiply some amount based on my new angle ($\Theta + \phi$)? The idea behind it is to save time on computation, if possible.

Example:

Taking the example of A, let's add (or multiply) some value of X which will be equal to the new value of A at ($\Theta + \phi$):

$$A + X = a^{2}(\sin \Theta + \phi)^{2}+b^{2}(\cos \Theta + \phi)^{2}$$
We know A to be equal to:
$$a^{2}(\sin \Theta)^{2}+b^{2}(\cos \Theta)^{2} + X = a^{2}(\sin \Theta + \phi)^{2}+b^{2}(\cos \Theta + \phi)^{2}$$

$$ X = a^{2}(\sin \Theta + \phi)^{2}+b^{2}(\cos \Theta + \phi)^{2} - a^{2}(\sin \Theta)^{2}+b^{2}(\cos \Theta)^{2}$$

Is this mathematically possible? If so, can we find the value of X? Obviously, to have the whole exercise to be useful, **X must also be easily computable/derivable,** i.e. the above must be simplified somewhat, allowing us to find the coefficients at rotation ($\Theta + \phi$) with much ease:
$$A' = A + X$$

... and similarly for other coefficients.

Comment: There’s nothing special about conics here. Do what one would do to rotate the graph of _any_ equation: Invert the coordinate transformation formula given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#In_two_dimensions), i.e., apply a rotation through $-\phi$, and substitute into your original equation.

Comment: Hi, I was thinking more along the lines of using incremental computing. Something like differentiating w.r.t $\Theta$ and then adding the result to the previous value of the coefficient like A. Do you think that's correct? A' = A + a^{2) - b^{2} 2 sin($\phi$) cos($\phi$), for example.

Comment: Well, the correct difference between $A$ and $A'$ is $(a^2-b^2)\sin(\phi)\sin(2\Theta-\phi)$, and the correct linearization via $d/d\Phi$ is $(a^2-b^2)\phi\sin(2\Theta)$, so the approximation is only good when $\phi$ is both small enough for $\sin\phi\approx\phi$ **and** $\phi$ is small relative to $2\Theta$. If you use this repeatedly, the error will start building pretty quickly after a while. Seems to me that it’s just as easy to apply the correct rotation. The resulting expressions aren’t all that much more costly computationally.

Comment: How about $A' = A + (a^2 - b^2) * 2 * sin(\Theta + \phi) * cos(\Theta + \phi)$ Would that lead to any errors? I agree computationally the only thing being achieved here is that we are avoiding squaring the sine and cosines and hence not worth the effort. But I am curious now to know if it's mathematically correct. Thanks!

Comment: What would you consider “correct?” You’re essentially approximating nonlinear functions with linear ones.